# Getting data from 3rd instance of _ of a variable using awk

Tags: awk

I have two requirements here:

I have a variable like **`imp_1`** which has value like below:

```
DI_DGF_PP_Cust_support
DI_DGF_PP_Call_Detail
DI_DGF_PP_Area
```

I want the value from the third instance on "**`_`**" i.e

```
Cust_support
Call_Detail
Area
```

I am using the below but it's not working.

```
imp_2=`awk -F _ '{print $4}'` "$imp_1"
```

Also,

I want to look for the value of **`imp_2`** in some other variable `$imp_3` get the `$imp_3-` `$imp_2`.(Minus result)

For ex:

**`$imp_2-`**

```
Cust_support
Call_Detail
Area
```

**`$imp-3`**

```
Cust_support
Call_Detail
Area
Call_detail
Finance_Detail
Marketing_Analysis
```

so **`$imp_3` `-$imp_2`**

```
Call_detail
Finance_Detail
Marketing_Analysis
```

Checked the below:

```
comm -3 <(echo "SDH") <(echo "ADP_DATA")
```

result:

```
        ADP_DATA
SDH
```

Comment: Show an example of variables `$imp_3` `$imp_2`, with the result after subtraction.

Comment: Added sample for the subtract case

Comment: @user3901666: Why you are comparing `SDH` with `APP_DATA`, did you mean to use them as variables? you are comparing literal strings

Comment: I mean .i just tried to replace one value from the variable in both $imp3 and $imp2  and check the result

Answer (score 2):

Along with using `awk`, using `cut` is much more simple. Just define the delimiter and the number of fields to parse from

```
imp_2=$(printf '%s\n' "$imp_1" | cut -d_ -f4-)
printf '%s\n' "$imp_2"
```

For the `imp_3 - imp_2`, i.e. non unique lines between two variables, use the `comm` utility

```
comm -3 <(echo "$imp_3") <(echo "$imp_2")
```

Comment: Perfect!! Thanks!!
Can you also let me know how to subtract two variables?

Comment: Added sample for the subtract case

Comment: @user3901666: See update. Mark the answer accepted if it solved your problem completely

Comment: you want to sort the inputs to `comm`

Comment: s3=$(comm -3 <(echo "$imp_3") <(echo "$imp_2"))-- This is throwing some error. Is this fine?

Comment: checked on one sample, but its not giving the desired desired using comm

Comment: @user3901666 check for typos. I get the results you were asking for with the sample you provided. And you where missing quotes, try `s3="$(comm -3 <(echo "$imp_3") <(echo "$imp_2"))"`

Answer (score 0):

Below is the try which i attempted for imp1

```
echo $imp_1|awk -F "_" '{$1=$2=$3="";print $0}' |sed -r "s/^\s+//g"|sed -r "s/\s+$//g"|sed "s/ /_/g"
```

output

```
Cust_support
Call_Detail
Area
```